# React Routes - How to load a new page when dynamic segment changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I navigate to a path that points to the same component? I need the new page to be reloaded from scratch, but as it is now, it seems like it remains mounted and some data is only updated according to the params I pass.

The path "artist/:id" corresponds to this route. It is a page that has information about an artist and a list of related artists. If you click on a related artist, it redirects to his page -> "artist/:id_related_artist". I want to know how to make sure that when the dynamic segment (:id) is modified, a new page is loaded from scratch.

This is how I defined the index.js with the routes. The idea is that when the id param changed, the component would be replaced. But it doesn't work.

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          element={<App key={() => useLocation().pathname} />}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/artist/:id"
          element={<Artist key={() => useParams().id}/>}
        ></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And this is the part that calls the route for the related artist:

```
function handleSelectArtisttt(relatedArtist) {
    navigate(`/artist/${relatedArtist.id}`, {
      state: { ...relatedArtist, searchValue: String(state.searchValue) },
    });
  }
```

How can I solve this? I'm learning React.

I tried using navigate(0) after calling the route, but the problem is that the information passed as parameters is changed before the reload occurs. Also, I use window.scrollTo(0, 0); and it doesn't work properly in these cases.

Comment: You shouldn't need the component to remount, the component should react to the prop/state/context change (the id changing) and load / replace the data for the new artist. You can pretty this up with what ever loading / validating UI you want (loading indicator, skeletons, blank space, etc).

Comment: But the idea of the functionality is precisely to load a new page. There are directives that need to be executed when the data is changed, and they only happen when the page is mounted. There are also some animations that need to take place.

Comment: You can't call React hooks conditionally or in nested functions, this breaks the rules of hooks. The `Artist` component should implement a `useEffect` hook to "react" to the route path parameter value updating and rerun any logic. It's a complete waste to unmount and remount the same component just because a prop or path param value updated.